# Git pull from another repository without history

Tags: git, laravel, github, repository, revision-history

I'm here because : I try to connect my repository to another in order to keep "up to date" but I'm trying not to pull the whole history of the other repo...

To explain, I use Laravel 5 (https://github.com/laravel/laravel) and I have created my own master (which is a fork of laravel/v5.0.1) to customize some things inside (like a css framework, some generic layouts, etc.) -> call it "azurky-repo/master"

And now I feel like updating my repository with lastest commits of laravel/master but each time I pull from laravel/master, my "git log" is full of commits (about 4400) and I don't want this. *(I'm a kind of maniac guy who wants a clean repository and a lot of control over everything ^^)*.

In an ideal world, I would like to **update only the files** and then just make **one commit with a message like 'Update from Laravel/master'**. 
Without any other extra history entry or refs that I don't need at all.

Tried without success :

```
git pull --depth 1 laravel master
```

I still have an extra history entry... (the last laravel/master commit message and didn't succeed in amending... maybe missed something)

Someone has an idea (or am I the only mad guy to try a thing like this..)?

P.S :

To clarify, I would like to have the same result as if I :

- clone the laster version of my repo (azursky-repo/master)
- download all the updated files from laravel/master
- overwrite my repository with this files
- merge manually each modified files
- And then push to azursky-repo/master with "Update from laravel/masgter"

The matter is in fact I'm not masochist and don't want to bypass the merging ability of git... ^^

So I feel like having, finally, this history :

- Rev1 : "Inital commit - Laravel v5.0.1"
- Rev2 : "Implementation of Foundation5 / SASS / Gulp"
- Rev3 : "Update from laravel/master"

In place of :

- Rev1 : "Inital commit - Laravel v5.0.1"
- Rev2 : "Implementation of Foundation5 / SASS / Gulp"
- 4400 commits from Laravel/master
- Rev4403 : "Merge conflict from updating laravel/master" (something like this)

Do you see what I hope ?

Comment: This sounds a bit like premature optimization. Git's history is pretty good at compacting things. In Laravel's case it's 1.6m vs. 12m. Not a huge difference considering that there are over 4,000 commits.

Comment: No it's not a matter of optimization, I just don't want this extra commits history at all. As if I had download the updated files and overwritten my repository with and merged manually. But I appreciate the auto merge that's why I'm trying to do it with Git, I'm not masochist. Gonna clarify below (because I haven't the right to edit =( )

Comment: You should always be able to edit your own question. Don't put clarifications in an answer, it is likely to get removed.

Comment: Why not clone Laravel and work from there instead of copying it in the "initial commit"? That way you can always work on your own stuff and every once in a while merge the current development from Laravel into your own branch.

Comment: Edited the question to be clearer. About your answer I would say "maybe" but I don't really see what you're trying to explain ^^ What would be the result of this "merging into my own branch" ?

Comment: It would be the answer to your requirement in the first sentence: You "keep up to date".

Comment: But what about the history and the 4400 extra commits from laravel/master that I don't want to grab ?

Comment: I think the best answer to this is "`git` doesn't work that way. If you want to work that way, `git` is not the tool you want to use."...

Comment: Really doesn't sound good because of Laravel being on Git...
If you were me, what would you do with this kind of "project" ?

Comment: @Azursky I would work with `git` the way it is meant to be worked with - i.e. each repository contains the full history of the project - and not try to shoe-horn it into "this is the way I wish it worked"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got it !

The answer is just a simple :

```
git reset HEAD
```

Sorry I'm really new to git so I found the solution this afternoon after reading questions about this kind of subjects. Didn't understood everything about indexes, now it's better =)

So from beginning I have a fresh repo with just an initial commit :

```
git clone git@mygitserver:myuser/myrepo
git log
commit 1
   Initial commit - Laravel v5.0.1
```

Then I pull from laravel/master

```
git remote add laravel https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git
git pull laravel master
git reset HEAD
git add --all
git commit -m 'Update from laravel/master'
git log
commit 2
    Update from laravel/master
commit 1  
    Initial commit - Laravel v5.0.1
```

That seems OK, then I make an other modif. to to be sure :

```
git rm -rf resources/assets/less/
git add --all
git commit -m 'Suppression de bootstrap'
git log 
commit 3
    Suppression de bootstrap
commit 2
    Update from laravel/master
commit 1  
    Initial commit - Laravel v5.0.1
```

N.B : I write commit 1/2/3 to simplify of course

And then to be extra-sure :

```
git push origin master
```

And check on the repository web page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XMzb.jpg
(sorry haven't the right to put the img)

That's OK for me =)

Finally I like the way git works =)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit of a "hack" way to do it. But, you could just git pull from that main repo, then rm the .git files in the folder, then `git init` and then `git push -force` to your repo version each time you wish to pull from the main repo.

Comment: Yeah I thinks it would do the job but what a "hard way" to do it ^^
Gonna wait to see if someone have a softer idea =)

Comment: Based on your own answer and after dealing with some issues like cleaning the tags I created a [gist with instructions you can follow here](https://gist.github.com/krlozadan/4b75255b88d7a1504e5e632cb817c3f5)